# background-image in jQuery won't work if full URL not given

Tags: jquery

Would anyone tell me why do I have to give full URL to get the image background working? Example codes in jQuery code below works for many people on this post but not for me! Do I miss something? Image is accessible through the URL too.

**Note:** I know there are 100s of same question and went through the most. I played with single and double quotes as well.

Thanks

**JQ CODE**

```
//This works fine
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css('background-image', 'url("http://localhosttt/web/images/message_icons.png")');

//These won't work
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('images/message_icons.png')");
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('/images/message_icons.png')");
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('./images/message_icons.png')");
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('../images/message_icons.png')");
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('web/images/message_icons.png')");
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('/web/images/message_icons.png')");
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('./web/images/message_icons.png')");
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('../web/images/message_icons.png')");
```

**ROOT STRUCTURE**

```
web
->images
  ->message_icons.png
->scripts
  ->myjs.js
  ->mycss.css
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="response_table">
    <div class="response_table_row">
        <div class="response_table_cell logo"><div></div></div>
        <div class="response_table_cell message"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.response_table_cell.logo div
{
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    /*background-image: url('../images/message_icons.png');*/ //WORKS FINE when ENABLED
}
```

Comment: where have you written your css? Is it embedded or external (if external specify the root Structure of css file)

Comment: Sorry forgot it. It is in the ROOT with js. Post updated.

Comment: in you ROOT STRUCTURE, can you please mention HTML file as well?

Comment: @Ashish Kumar - No. I'm using framework so HTML is not there.

Comment: from the information you have provided `$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('../images/message_icons.png')");`, possible try `$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css("background-image","url('..\images\message_icons.png')");` as it may be due to OS. What framework are you using?

Comment: It didn't work. I'm using CodeIgniter.

Comment: @MadMax have you understood the answer.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried nearly everything. Forward/backward slashes, single/double quotes, single/double/no dots so on. I' tried on Ubuntu as well as Win.

Comment: then you are in big trouble. OK, so do one thing, try getting `path` of any other image which have same location. and then you can set the path accordingly.

Comment: like `$("img").eq(0).attr("src")` this will give the idea that what should be the exact path

Answer (score 0):

The path can either be full or relative (of course if the image is from another domain it must be full) if you are using css for same.

whereas you need to give full path (or replace part of path and then re assign it) while assigning it through javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Adding **CSS** using **Jquery** then **Jquery** adds your **CSS** to your `inline style`.

like : `<div style="backgroun-image:url("...")">`

So you have to specify the **path** from your **html file** to access your **image**.

If you are accessing from **External css** file then at that time you have to specify the path from the **css file**.

Hope you understood.

Let have a director like below

```
-->Images
   -->1.png
-->jsandcss
   -->javasc.js
   -->mycss.css
myhtmlfile.html
```

in mycss.css ill write the code as `background-image:url('../Images/1.png');`

but when i add using jquery ill make it as `background-image:url('Images/1.png');`

Answer (score 0):

Since it was very urgent, I had to change the coding to solve the problem.

Additional part in HTML: (I can hard-code it in JQ but base_url differs too!)

```
<input id="base_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhosttt/" />
```

Pick base_url in JQ to set full URL:

```
var base_url = $('#base_url').val();
$('.response_table_cell.logo div').css({'background-image':'url("' + base_url + 'web/images/message_icons.png")'});
```